# How can i make nested ui-view work in html?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is my code, I need `ui-view="tabs"` to work properly, but when i add it inside `ui-view="details"` an error occured

> (angular.js:13550TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined)

```js
$stateProvider
.state('home',{
  views:{
    'tabs' :{
      templateUrl:   'http://v.eyp.iypcdn.com/static/mobile/js/app/html/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeController'
    }
  }
})
.state('categories', {
  views:{
    'tabs' :{
      templateUrl: 'http://v.eyp.iypcdn.com/static/mobile/js/app/html/categories.html',
      controller: 'CategoriesController'
    }
  }
})
.state('categoryDetails',{
  views:{
    'details': {
      templateUrl : 'http://v.eyp.iypcdn.com/static/mobile/js/app/html/categoryDetails.html',
      controller: 'CategoryDetailsCtrl'
    }
  },
  params:{
    cat: 'all'
  }
})
```

```html
<div ui-view="details">
  <div  ng-controller="TabsController" class="tabsdemoDynamicTabs" layout="column">
    <div ui-view="tabs" layout-fill class="demo-tab tab{{index%4}}">
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your HTML suggests that `tabs` are nested view inside the `details` view. So, you'll need to define the state information accordingly.

try this:

`.state('categoryDetails.home',{` & `.state('categoryDetails.categories',{`

Hope this solves it.. :)